# How to send '@' when type 'à' twice ("àà" = @) using AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a question related to Hotstrings in AHK V 1.1.36.02.

I want to write the character `@` When I type `à` twice (`àà` = `@`).

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
:*:àà::@
```

Notes :

- I do have an actual 'à' key on my keyboard layout (it's French)
- When I replace the 'àà' with other character like 'bb' it works (:*:bb::@)
- I use VS Code.
- Operating system 64bit.

Please help!. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you type `à` on your keyboard?

Comment: I do have an actual 'à' key on my keyboard layout.

Comment: If it's for VS Code specifically, why not just use some internal functionality of that to achieve this? E.g. should be possible with chord hotkey.

Answer (score 1):

Try the send command:

```
:*:àà:: 
    Send @
return
```

or the [Text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotstrings.htm#T) (**recommended**, more reliable):

```
:T*:àà::@
```

or

```
:*:àà::
    Send {Text}@
return
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to use
[Hotstrings](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotstrings.htm).

The correct syntax for what you were trying to do is :

```
::àà::@
```

However, note that this requires typing an
[Ending Character](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotstrings.htm#EndChars)
at the end of the hotstring, which makes its usage a bit awkward.

Comment: ::àà::@ does'nt work

Comment: This might be because you're typing the character `à` using more than one keyboard key.  In this case the situation might be more complex and may require using a simpler character than `à`.

Comment: From your added information I understand that this is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0):

To create a hotstring that converts "àà" to "@" using AutoHotkey, you can use the following code:

```
::àà::@
```

Make sure you have AutoHotkey installed on your computer and that the script containing this hotstring is running. The double colon `::` is used to define the hotstring, and `@` is the replacement text.

If this code is not working for you, there might be another hotstring or script that is conflicting with it. You can try adding a `$` symbol in front of the hotstring to make it work even if there are other hotstrings that start with "àà". Here's an example:

```
$::àà::@
```

Additionally, ensure that the text editor or application you're using supports AutoHotkey hotstrings. Some applications have their own text processing mechanisms that might interfere with AutoHotkey's functionality.

If the issue persists, please provide more details about the environment you're using (operating system, text editor, AutoHotkey version, etc.), and I'll be glad to assist you further.

Comment: The issue stills persist.
I am sure there is no any another hotstring or script that is conflicting with it.
I have added some informations in the question I hope you read it again. Thanks